# Better way to print string casted *args?

Tags: python

I've made a simple function to send any message to stderr along with a prefix:

```
import sys

def error(*message):
  print('Error:', ' '.join(map(str, message)), file = sys.stderr)
```

The function may receive an exception object or something different from 
plain string.

In order to show a clean message I added this `' '.join(map(str, message))` block.

I'm new to Python and I wonder if there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that other question has a really misleading title compared to the actual problem ...

Comment: It's still the exact same topic. If you want to post code snippets, use a repository like Sourceforge or Github.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

```
import sys

def error(*message):
  print('Error:', *message, file = sys.stderr)
```